# Prevent deletion if is a child in a self-referencing belongsToMany association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my `ModelsTable` I have two virtual fields for a self-referencing belongsToMany association between a model and another (the child is the accessory of the parent and it can have multiple child) using an `AccessoriesTable` (with `model_id` and `accessory_id` columns) to do the link.

```
$this->belongsToMany('AccessoryModels', [
    'className' => 'Models',
    'through' => 'Accessories',
    'foreignKey' => 'model_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'accessory_id'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('ParentAccessoryModels', [
    'className' => 'Models',
    'through' => 'Accessories',
    'foreignKey' => 'accessory_id',
    'targetForeignKey' => 'model_id'
]);
```

When deleting a model, I want to be sure it is not used as an accessory (a child) of another model. So I tried to create a custom rule in `ModelsTable` but this won't work (it won't delete any model even if it's not an accessory of another model).

```
$rules->addDelete(function ($entity, $options) use($rules) {
    $rule = $rules->existsIn(['accessory_id'], 'ParentAccessoryModels');
    return !$rule($entity, $options);
}, 'isNotAnAccessory');
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you checked whether your rule is actually being invoked? And if it is being invoked, have a look at [**DebugKit's**](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3.x/en/index.html) SQL tab and check what exactly the query looks like that is being generated from your rule.

Comment: Yes it is invoked because if I only do a `return false;` in `addDelete` then nothing can be deleted. And strangely now by retesting with the `addDelete` method in my question, I cannot delete anything. In the SQL log I only have a `SELECT` fetching the infos from the Models I want to delete. But nothing concerning the Accessories table. Is there a way to output in a log or something what is the content of `$rules->existsIn(['accessory_id'], 'ParentAccessoryModels')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using a `beforeDelete` event :

```
public function beforeDelete($event, $entity, $options)
{
    $parentsModels = $this->get($entity->id, ['contain' => 'ParentAccessoryModels']);
    if (!empty($parentsModels->parent_accessory_models)) {
        return false;
    };
}
```